What is this display for on the Embraer E175?
Caught my attention, never had I seen a display in this kind of overhead position in an aircraft. What is it for?


Source of the photo?

@RalphJ and @ Michael actual aircraft, it seems not all ERJs have that, an ERJ pilot out there should probably know. I found it on google images, can't find again the same picture link, found another one https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5139/5529861633_4822a964c5_b.jpg

still the coolest yokes I've seen

That is the screen for the Cockpit Door Surveillance System (CDSS) which can show a live video feed of the area in front of the cockpit door. This allows pilots to decide whether it's safe to open the door when someone requests access to the cockpit, e.g. the other pilot returning from the lavatory.
I couldn't find the exact model used on this Embraer, but here is a similar system:


Three cameras are located in the passenger cabin ceiling panels. One camera is installed immediately in front of the cockpit door. Once camera is above the forward passenger door and one is above the forward service door. The combination of camera locations provides full visibility of the forward passenger cabin area from in front of the passenger door, right across to the service door, including the galley area. When the pilot is checking the system to identify who is requesting access to the cockpit, it is also possible to see that there is nobody else hiding behind the toilet bulkhead or in the galley. It is also possible to identify that the person outside the galley door is not under threat or duress.

(AD Aerospace: Cockpit Door Surveillance System (CDSS))
The newer E-Jets E2 use a slightly different model:

(image source)

I was considering a smart-mouth answer of how its a rearview mirror (cos its in a similar relative position to one in a car)  but dang it basically is !

@Criggie GMTA I was going to say "it's that extra rear view mirror so you can see what the kids are up to in the back seat of the Sienna .."
